# need clarification on where not exists clause

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to insert only those records into #AltDealNames table for which DealName exists in #DistDeal table but not in #AltDealNames table. For this I am trying not exists clause. But it is not working as expected. Query is simply dumping records into #AltDealNames table.

```
insert into #AltDealNames
select d.DealName, d.ManagerScrubbed, d.BbgDealName, t.TrancheName,  t.StreetCusip, t.ISIN, t.BbgTrancheName 
from metric..Deal d join metric..Tranche t on d.DealName = t.DealName
where not exists(select 1 from #DistDeal dd join #AltDealNames ad on ad.DealName = dd.DealName)
```

Please help me to know if I am doing something wrong while building query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want an `exists` clause for `#DistDeal` and a `not exists` for `#AltDealNames`:

```
insert into #AltDealNames
    select d.DealName, d.ManagerScrubbed, d.BbgDealName, t.TrancheName, 
           t.StreetCusip, t.ISIN, t.BbgTrancheName 
    from metric..Deal d join
         metric..Tranche t
         on d.DealName = t.DealName
    where exists (select 1 from #DistDeal dd where dd.DealName = d.DealName) and
          not exists (select 1 from #AltDealNames ad on ad.DealName = dd.DealName);
```

Note:  when using `insert`, you should always include the list of column names.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your reply, but may be I misunderstood that where not exist clause works on record by record basis, like insert 1st record  if it doesn't exists then 2nd then 3rd. But it appears that where not exists clause will work on complete result set of outer query.

Comment: @ShashiShankar . . . The `select` is evaluated completely before the `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the optimizer sets up the actual physical query, the "where not exists" clause might run first, before anything is inserted by this query.  Ie., it would only filter on values in #AltDealNames that were there from a previous query.

If you're trying to avoid inserting DealName values that are in #DistDeal, then maybe you want:

```
insert into #AltDealNames
select d.DealName, d.ManagerScrubbed, d.BbgDealName, t.TrancheName,  
   t.StreetCusip, t.ISIN, t.BbgTrancheName
from metric..Deal d 
   join metric..Tranche t on d.DealName = t.DealName
where not exists(select 1 from #DistDeal dd 
             where d.DealName = dd.DealName)   -- Changed line
```